# How can I extract columns of data from a CSV file and define them as x and y variables, then plot them in python using pylab?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot

I've got a CSV file with data such as

```
350, -0.042447984
349, -0.041671798
348, -0.04158416
347, -0.041811798
346, -0.041716855
```

Though I've got a lot more data. What I am trying to do is have the first column (350, 349, etc.) be defined as my x-values, and the second column (-0.042447984, -0.041671798, etc.) be defined as my y-values. This is my code so far:

```
import pylab
x=[350, 349, 348, 347, 346]
y=[-0.042447984, -0.041671798, -0.04158416, -0.041811798, -0.041716855]
pylab.plot(x, y)
pylab.show()
```

However, instead of manually entering the numbers I'm trying to write a program that will extract column 1 from my CSV file as the x-values and column 2 as the y-values. It's probably something much simpler than I'm trying to make it. I'm new at python, so bear with me!

Comment: I have, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your csv file is in the format you've described, I'd probably use `loadtxt`.

```
>>> d = numpy.loadtxt("plot1.csv", delimiter=",")
>>> d
array([[  3.50000000e+02,  -4.24479840e-02],
       [  3.49000000e+02,  -4.16717980e-02],
       [  3.48000000e+02,  -4.15841600e-02],
       [  3.47000000e+02,  -4.18117980e-02],
       [  3.46000000e+02,  -4.17168550e-02]])
```

and there are lots of ways to get `x` and `y` from this:

```
>>> x,y = numpy.loadtxt("plot1.csv", delimiter=",", unpack=True)
>>> x
array([ 350.,  349.,  348.,  347.,  346.])
>>> y
array([-0.04244798, -0.0416718 , -0.04158416, -0.0418118 , -0.04171685])
```

or `x,y = d.T` or `d[:,0], d[:,1]`, etc.

The more complicated the format, the better off you are to work with the `csv` module directly.  Although `loadtxt` has lots of options, often you need finer control than it gives.

Comment: I agree, I usually start with loadtxt, move up to [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) if I need a little more flexibility, and then csv if the first two don't pan out.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started:

```
import csv

with open('data.txt') as inf:
    x = []
    y = []
    for line in csv.reader(inf):
        tx, ty = line
        x.append(int(tx))
        y.append(float(ty))
```

lists `x`, and `y` will respectively contain:

```
[350, 349, 348, 347, 346]
[-0.042447984, -0.041671798, -0.04158416, -0.041811798, -0.041716855]
```

*Notes*:

Using `with` to open the file will take care of closing it when we're done with it or an exception is encountered. The [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module will read the input data line by line and split each line into a list based on the comma separator. The first item is converted to `int`, the second to `float` before being appended to the respective lists.

File `data.txt` contains your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is rather dated; however, for someone needing to get csv data plotted quickly, the following script will provide a good solution.

It shows how to import the data from the csv file and how to make a plot with matplotlib which will make a png and plot it.

Using the data of [Lake Huron](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/LakeHuron.csv) without headers, you get a nice plot.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange

#####################################
# instatiation of variables

filehandle = "lake_huron.csv"
x_data = []                         # makes a list
y_data = []                         # makes a list
png_filename = 'LakeData.png'

#####################################
# opening csv file and reading

my_file = open(filehandle, "rb")    # opens file for reading
data = csv.reader(my_file)          # saves file to variable "data"

#####################################
# saves csv data to x_data and y_data

for row in data:
    x_data.append(eval(row[1]))     # selects data from the ith row
    y_data.append(eval(row[2]))     # selects data from the ith row

#####################################
# closes csv file
my_file.close()                     # closes file




#####################################
# makes plot (show) and saves png

fig = plt.figure()                  # calls a variable for the png info

# defines plot's information (more options can be seen on matplotlib website)
plt.title("Level of Lake Huron from 1875 to 1972")      # plot name
plt.xlabel('Year')                                      # x axis label
plt.ylabel('Lake Level (in feet)')                      # y axis label
plt.xticks(arange(1875,1973,10))                        # x axis tick marks
plt.axis([1875,1973,573,584])                           # x and y ranges

# defines png size
fig.set_size_inches(10.5,5.5)                           # png size in inches

# plots the data from the csv above
plt.plot(x_data,y_data)

#saves png with specific resolution and shows plot
fig.savefig(png_filename ,dpi=600, bbox_inches='tight')     # saves png
plt.show()                                                  # shows plot

plt.close()                                                 # closes pylab
```